# Why is FFMPEG stopping before the re-encapsulation finishes?

Tags: ffmpeg, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running a straight up re-encapsulation of an H264/AAC video in a Flash container to an MP4 container using FFMPEG. However, it quits only a second later after transferring only a few megabytes of data. Why is FFMPEG quitting before the re-encapsulation completes?

```
$ ffmpeg -i "input.flv" -c copy -copyts "output.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-54803-g454c89d Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 18 2013 20:42:15 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --disable-yasm
  libavutil      52. 40.100 / 52. 40.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 81.101 /  3. 81.101
  libswscale      2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
Input #0, flv, from 'input.flv':
  Metadata:
    audiosize       : 15787550
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    datasize        : 82829154
    videosize       : 65650649
    hasAudio        : true
    hasCuePoints    : false
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    hasVideo        : true
    lasttimestamp   : 1306
    metadatacreator : flvtool++ (Facebook, Motion project, dweatherford)
    totalframes     : 32659
    encoder         : Lavf54.6.100
  Duration: 00:21:47.32, start: 0.057000, bitrate: 506 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 544x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 400 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    audiosize       : 15787550
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    datasize        : 82829154
    videosize       : 65650649
    hasAudio        : true
    hasCuePoints    : false
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    hasVideo        : true
    lasttimestamp   : 1306
    metadatacreator : flvtool++ (Facebook, Motion project, dweatherford)
    totalframes     : 32659
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 544x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 400 kb/s, 16k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, 96 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 3362 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    8475kB time=00:02:14.45 bitrate= 516.4kbits/s    
video:6766kB audio:1575kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.601224%
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it seems to have been a **truncated download**. I re-downloaded the file and it now seems to be slightly larger and works perfectly.